# Create slidable ListView in Windows 10 UWP apps like in Maps app

Tags: listview, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm creating UWP Application where I need to show an array of results in a sliding menu. The sliding menu is scrollable and can be slide to change it's height **like the search results in Maps Application in windows 10 mobile**.
I can't find any tutorial to create such an experience.

Thanks in advance

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `UserControl` and [UIElement.RenderTransform property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.RenderTransform);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0)&rd=true) to do this.

Here is a sample:

UserControl "SlidableControl" xaml:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="SlidRoot" ManipulationMode="All"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ManipulationStarted="SlidRoot_ManipulationStarted"
          Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" ManipulationDelta="SlidRoot_ManipulationDelta"
          ManipulationCompleted="SlidRoot_ManipulationCompleted">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="SlidArea" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="{x:Bind maxheight}" Background="AliceBlue"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Child="{x:Bind SlidChild, Mode=OneWay}">
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="SlidAreaTransform" TranslateY="{Binding ElementName=SlidTitle, Path=RenderTransform.TranslateY, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </Border.RenderTransform>
        </Border>
        <Grid x:Name="SlidTitle" Background="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="SlidTitleTransform" />
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TextBlock Text="&#xE76F;" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="25" />
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

UserControl "SlidableControl" code behind:

```cs
private double maxheight;
private double Y;
private double finalY;

public SlidableControl()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    maxheight = Window.Current.Bounds.Height / 3;
    SlidArea.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private void SlidRoot_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SlidArea.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    SlidTitleTransform.TranslateY = -maxheight;
}

private void SlidRoot_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Y = e.Delta.Translation.Y;
    finalY = SlidTitleTransform.TranslateY + Y;
    if (Y >= 0 && finalY <= 0)
    {
        if (finalY < maxheight)
            SlidTitleTransform.TranslateY = finalY;
        else
            SlidTitleTransform.TranslateY = 0;
    }
    else if (Y < 0 && finalY >= -maxheight)
    {
        if (finalY > -maxheight)
            SlidTitleTransform.TranslateY = finalY;
        else
        {
            SlidTitleTransform.TranslateY = -maxheight;
        }
    }
}

private void SlidRoot_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (finalY <= -maxheight)
    {
        SlidArea.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        SlidTitleTransform.TranslateY = 0;
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SlidChild", typeof(UIElement), typeof(SlidableControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public UIElement SlidChild
{
    get { return (UIElement)GetValue(ChildProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ChildProperty, value); }
}
```

You can see from my code, that I expose the `SlidChild` property, so you can add any other control to this "SlidableControl" for example like this:

```xml
<local:SlidableControl VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <local:SlidableControl.SlidChild>
        <ListView x:Name="listView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding txt}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </local:SlidableControl.SlidChild>
</local:SlidableControl>
```

This is a very early version of control, you can expose some other properties, like control's height.

Here is my [demo](https://github.com/GraceFeng/SlidableControl), you can have a test.

This is the rendering image of my test:
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help , we need to help us in the our case in the Answer Box below .

Comment: @Grace Feng Please Is it possible to change the position of the list from top to bottom ?

Comment: @OXXY, OK, I will add a new answer, next time you may create a new question.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I can this time also if you want :)

Comment: @OXXY, it's OK, I've already added a new answer, please check it.  :) I you have other more questions about this, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `UserControl` to do this.

XAML:

```xml
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="Area1" Grid.Row="0" Height="{x:Bind childheight}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="AliceBlue"></Border>
        <Grid x:Name="SlidButton" Background="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1"
              ManipulationStarted="SlidButton_ManipulationStarted" ManipulationCompleted="SlidButton_ManipulationCompleted" 
              ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationDelta="SlidButton_ManipulationDelta">
            <TextBlock Text="&#xE76F;" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="15" />
        </Grid>
        <Border x:Name="Area2" Grid.Row="2" Height="{x:Bind childheight}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent"></Border>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

code behind:

```cs
private double height;
private double childheight;

public SlidableView()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height * 2 - 40;
    childheight = Window.Current.Bounds.Height - 40;
}

private void SlidButton_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    scrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
}

private void SlidButton_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    scrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
}

private static double Y;

private void SlidButton_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Y = Y + e.Delta.Translation.Y;
    scrollViewer.ChangeView(null, -Y, null);
}
```

This is a very simple version works on mobile, when it is applied on PC, please change the "height" and "childheight" like this:

```
height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height * 2 - 20;
childheight = Window.Current.Bounds.Height - 20;
```

And when I say this is a very simple version, because I didn't expose any property of this usercontrol, you can expose the both child property of two `Border` controls as it in my last answer.

Answer (score 0):

We Are looking to make modify on the behavior of your example in above, we want to change the behavior as the following image  (the list should be on the map (blue Section) and the list motion from bottom to top as the image), what we should to change to do it?

[image]

Comment: OK, I will add a new answer, next time you may create a new question.