# Can't find the bing maps panel control on win 10

Tags: xaml, windows-10-universal

I am looking for the name of the control that open from the bottom in bing maps on windows phone 10. It opens when you tap on a pin on the map.

Thanks.

Comment: Without a visual (since I don't have a win phone on me) are you talking about a [CommandBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/app-bars)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I think what you need is the control in the following image:

[image]

There is no such official control, you will need to create a usercontrol by yourself.

You can refer to my another case: [Create slidable ListView in Windows 10 UWP apps like in Maps app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202429/create-slidable-listview-in-windows-10-uwp-apps-like-in-maps-app/36260862#36260862), in this case I gave an answer creating a slidable control which can slid from top to bottom, you can change it to slid from bottom to top.